# PLSQL cursor loop with data from two tables and a COUNT

Tags: sql, loops, plsql, count, cursor

I have two tables:

1. table carowner

```
CREATE TABLE carowner(
pnr VARCHAR2(13) PRIMARY KEY,
prename VARCHAR2(20),
surname VARCHAR2(20));
```

2. table vehicle

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle(
regnr VARCHAR2(6) PRIMARY KEY,
pnr REFERENCES carowner(pnr)
model VARCHAR2(20));
```

I need to write a code that creates the following output for each car owner, using PLSQL and a cursor loop,:

**pnr, prename, surname, number of cars: ___**

I struggle getting the number of cars each carowner has in the output.

The code I have figured out so far is:

```
declare
cursor c_ownerinfo is select c.pnr,c.prename,c.surname,count(v.regnr) nr_cars
                   from carowner c,vehicle v
                   where c.pnr=v.pnr
                   group by c.pnr,c.prename,c.surname
                   order by c.pnr;
v_prename carowner.prename%type;
v_surname carowner.surname%type;
v_pnr carowner.pnr%type;
v_regnr vehicle.regnr%type;
begin
    if not c_ownerinfo%isopen then
        open c_ownerinfo;
    end if;
    loop
        fetch c_ownerinfo
        into v_pnr,v_prename,v_surname,v_regnr;
        exit when c_ownerinfo%notfound;
            dbms_output.put_line(v_pnr||', '||v_prename||', '||v_surname||', nr of cars: ');
    end loop;
close c_ownerinfo;
end;
/
```

The code is working but does not include the number of cars each car owner has in the output.
Does anyone have an idea how to include the number of cars? In a normal SELECT, I would just use a JOIN and COUNT(vehicle.regnr), but here I am not sure how it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that "normal SELECT" differs from what you have to do here? It does not. So, if you manage to write a "normal SELECT" (the one that returns desired result), just put it into CURSOR declaration and it should work.

Comment: Of course this code does not print what you have not requested. How the DBMS should know your requirement?

Comment: is the `v.regnr` the registration number of each vehicle? And therefore your output is looking to show the registration number of each vehicle per owner, along with how many vehicles that owner has? (e.g. if Bob Smith has 2 cars, you'd expect to see 2 rows in the output, something like `12345, Bob, Smith, 2` and `67890, Bob, Smith, 2`?

Comment: @Boneist thanks for your comment. Yes, the `v.regnr` is the registration number for each vehicle, and in `table vehicle` there is one row for each vehicle, and the FK references to the respective car owner in `table car owner`. If the car owner "Bob Smith" has 2 cars (two rows in table vehicle), I want the output to say `12345, Bob, Smith ,2`. 

The code I have written so far does not include the "2", since I am not sure how to do that. Do you have a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: So you want one row output per owner, with one of their vehicle's regnr shown plus the count? If so, as well as the count of the `v.regnr`, you want `min` or `max` it as well.

Comment: @Boneist, almost: I want one row output per owner, with the number of cars they have (the count of rows in table vehicle that refer to that owner). Registration number is irrelevant. Just how many unique registration numbers each car owner has is relevant.

The SELECT-code that I have written gives me just that:
`select c.pnr,c.prename,c.surname,count(v.regnr) nr_cars
 from carowner c,vehicle v
 where c.pnr=v.pnr
   group by c.pnr,c.prename,c.surname
   order by c.pnr;`

, but I don*t know how to transfer the last part (number of cars) to the cursor output `dbms_output.put_line`.

Comment: You are currently fetching the `count(v.regnr)` into the `v_regnr` variable. That's probably not the right variable to use - I would declare a new variable of integer datatype instead - but regardless, you would need to concatenate that variable into the `dbms_output` string, much like you have the others. What don't you understand about how to do that?